# Horizontal scrolling Marquee, My text insists on bunching together when function is acxtivated

Tags: javascript

So Im creating a vertically scrolling marquee, which uses javascript to alter the the top position of the text. A function runs at timed intervals creating the illusion of several groups of text moving vertically within the marquee from bottom to top and back again.
Everything is working fine **Except the groups of text insist of been bunched together at the top of the marquee.
Can anybody offer advice ???**

```js
window.onload = defineMarquee;

var timeID;
var marqueeTxt = new Array();
var marqueeOff = true;
var topPos= 20;

/* defineMarquee()
      Initializes the contents of the marquee, determines the
      top style positions of each marquee item, and sets the
      onclick event handlers for the document
*/
   function defineMarquee() {

   var topValue;

   var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

   for(var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++){
      if (allElems[i].className == "marqueeTxt") marqueeTxt.push(allElems[i]);
   }

//Extract the "top" CSS class from marqueeTxt

   for(var i = 0; i < marqueeTxt.length; i++){
      if(marqueeTxt[i].getComputedStyle) {
         topValue = marqueeTxt[i].getPropertyValue("top")
         marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topValue +"px";
       }
      else if (marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle) {
          topValue = marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle("top");
          marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topValue +"px";
      }

     
   }

   


   document.getElementById("startMarquee").onclick = startMarquee;
   document.getElementById("stopMarquee").onclick = stopMarquee;


}

/* startMarquee()
      Starts the marquee in motion
*/

   function startMarquee() {
      if(marqueeOff ==  true) {
         timeID = setInterval("moveText()", 50);
         marqueeOff = false;
      }
   }

/* stopMarquee()
   Stops the Marquee
*/

   function stopMarquee() {
      clearInterval(timeID);
      marqueeOff = true;
   }  

/* moveText ()
   move the text within the marquee in a vertical direction
*/

   function moveText() {

   

   for(var i = 0; i < marqueeTxt.length; i++) {
      if(marqueeTxt[i].getComputedStyle) {
      topPos = parseInt(marqueeTxt.getPropertyValue("top"));  
   } 
   else if(marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle) {
      topPos = parseInt(marqueeTxt.currentStyle("top"));
   }

   if(topPos < -110) {
      topPos = 700;
   } else { topPos -= 1;
   }

   marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topPos + "px";


}


}
```

```css
*                    {margin: 0px; padding: 0px}
body                 {font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}

#pageContent         {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 30px; width: 800px}

#links               {display: block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;
                      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,153, 102); float: left}
#links               {list-style-type: none}
#links li            {display: block; float: left; text-align: center; width: 19%}
#links li a          {display: block; width: 100%; text-decoration: none; color: black;
                      background-color: white}
#links li a:hover    {color: white; background-color: rgb(0,153,102)}

#leftCol             {clear: left; float: left}
h1                   {font-size: 24px; letter-spacing: 5px; color: rgb(0, 153,102)}

#main                {float: left; width: 450px; margin-left: 10px; 
                      padding-left: 10px; border-left: 1px solid rgb(0,153,102);
                      padding-bottom: 15px}
#main img            {float: right; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px}

#main p              {margin-bottom: 10px}

address              {width: 100%; clear: left; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px;
                      border-top: 1px solid black; text-align: center;
                      padding-bottom: 15px}

.marquee             {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
                      width: 280px; height: 300px;
                      background-color: rgb(0, 153, 102); color:white; 
                      border: 5px inset white; 
                      padding:0px; overflow:hidden; position:relative}

#marqueeTxt1         {font-size: 1.4em; letter-spacing: 0.15em; border-bottom: 1px solid white}
input                {width: 120px; margin: 5px; font-size: 0.9em}
#marqueeButtons      {width: 280px; text-align: center}

#marqueeTxt1         {position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt2         {position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt3         {position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt4         {position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt5         {position: absolute; top: 330px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt6         {position: absolute; top: 410px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt7         {position: absolute; top: 490px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt8         {position: absolute; top: 570px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt9         {position: absolute; top: 640px; left: 20px}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 4
   Case Problem 3

   BYSO Web Page
   Author: Gavin Macken
   Date: 28 Feb `15  

   Filename:         byso.htm
   Supporting files: bstyles.css, byso.jpg, bysologo.jpg, marquee.js
-->
   <title>Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra</title>
   <link href="bstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "marquee.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="marqueeForm" action="">
   <div id="pageContent">

      <div id="head"><img src="bysologo.jpg" alt="Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra" /></div>

      <ul id="links">
         <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About BYSO</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Our Director</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Join BYSO</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="leftCol">
      <div class="marquee">
         <div id="marqueeTxt1" class="marqueeTxt">
            Schedule of Events
         </div>
         <div id="marqueeTxt2" class="marqueeTxt">
            Holiday Concert<br />
            December 14, 7:30 PM<br /> 
            Boise Civic Center
         </div>
         <div id="marqueeTxt3" class="marqueeTxt">
            Christmas Concert<br /> 
            Dec. 16, 7 PM<br /> 
            Our Savior Episcopal Church
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt4" class="marqueeTxt">
            Spring Concert<br />
            Feb. 27, 7 PM<br /> 
            Boise Civic Center
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt5" class="marqueeTxt">
            Easter Fanfare<br />
            March 14, 9 PM<br />
            Our Savior Episcopal Church
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt6" class="marqueeTxt">
            High School MusicFest<br />
            May 2, 3 PM<br />
            Boise Central High School
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt7" class="marqueeTxt">
            Summer Concert<br />
            June 15, 7:30 PM<br />
            Frontier Concert Hall
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt8" class="marqueeTxt">
            Fourth Fest<br />
            July 4, 4 PM<br />
            Canyon View Park
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt9" class="marqueeTxt">
            Frontier Days<br />
            August 9, 1 PM<br />
            Boise Concert Hall
         </div>     
      </div>

      <div id="marqueeButtons">
         <input type="button" id="startMarquee" value="Start Marquee" />
         <input type="button" id="stopMarquee" value="Pause Marquee" />
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="main">
         <h1>Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra</h1>
         <img src="byso.jpg" alt="" />
         <p>The Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra has delighted audiences worldwide with 
            beautiful music while offering the highest quality musical training to over 
            1,000 teens throughout Idaho for the past 30 years. BYSO 
            has established an outstanding reputation for its high quality sound, its 
            series of commissioned works, and collaborations with prominent musical groups 
            such as the Idaho and Boise Symphony Orchestras, the Montana Chamber 
            Orchestra, the Boise Adult Choir and the Western Symphony Orchestra. 
            Last year the group was invited to serve as the U.S. representative to 
            the 7th Annual World Festival of youth orchestras in Poznan, Poland.</p>
         <p>Leading this success for the past decade has been Boise Symphony artistic 
            director Denise Young. In a concert review by John Aehl, music critic for 
            the <i>Boise Times</i>, Roger Adler writes, "It is a pleasure to report that 
            the orchestra is playing better than ever."</p>
      </div>

    <address>
    BYSO &#183; 300 Mountain Lane &#183; Boise, Idaho  83702 &#183; (208) 555 - 9114
    </address>


   </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at how you are setting the top value on your marqueeText objects, they are only 1 pixel apart.  Try spacing them out more.

Comment: ugh, the snippet is misbehaving, but you are using the topPos var as a global, so it is being set to the same for all of the different items, you need to use a closure

Comment: I think you could be onto to something Ray ...But when I declare the topPos variable inside  the movetext(), the text doesn't move

Comment: I'd like to manipulate the text without changing any of the properties in the CSS file...

Comment: We're do you think I should add a closure..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use relative positioning for `#marqueeTxt`:

```
#marqueeTxt1         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
...
```

Also setting a longer interval time and additional length onto the positioning might work better:

**Interval:**

```
timeID = setInterval("moveText()", 100);
```

**Position:**

```
if(topPos < -600) {
   topPos = 300;
```

```js
window.onload = defineMarquee;

var timeID;
var marqueeTxt = new Array();
var marqueeOff = true;
var topPos= 20;

/* defineMarquee()
      Initializes the contents of the marquee, determines the
      top style positions of each marquee item, and sets the
      onclick event handlers for the document
*/
   function defineMarquee() {

   var topValue;

   var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

   for(var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++){
      if (allElems[i].className == "marqueeTxt") marqueeTxt.push(allElems[i]);
   }

//Extract the "top" CSS class from marqueeTxt

   for(var i = 0; i < marqueeTxt.length; i++){
      if(marqueeTxt[i].getComputedStyle) {
         topValue = marqueeTxt[i].getPropertyValue("top")
         marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topValue +"px";
       }
      else if (marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle) {
          topValue = marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle("top");
          marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topValue +"px";
      }

     
   }

   


   document.getElementById("startMarquee").onclick = startMarquee;
   document.getElementById("stopMarquee").onclick = stopMarquee;


}

/* startMarquee()
      Starts the marquee in motion
*/

   function startMarquee() {
      if(marqueeOff ==  true) {
         timeID = setInterval("moveText()", 100);
         marqueeOff = false;
      }
   }

/* stopMarquee()
   Stops the Marquee
*/

   function stopMarquee() {
      clearInterval(timeID);
      marqueeOff = true;
   }  

/* moveText ()
   move the text within the marquee in a vertical direction
*/

   function moveText() {

   

   for(var i = 0; i < marqueeTxt.length; i++) {
      if(marqueeTxt[i].getComputedStyle) {
      topPos = parseInt(marqueeTxt.getPropertyValue("top"));  
   } 
   else if(marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle) {
      topPos = parseInt(marqueeTxt.currentStyle("top"));
   }

   if(topPos < -600) {
      topPos = 300;
   } else { topPos -= 1;
   }

   marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topPos + "px";


}


}
```

```css
*                    {margin: 0px; padding: 0px}
body                 {font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}

#pageContent         {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 30px; width: 800px}

#links               {display: block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;
                      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,153, 102); float: left}
#links               {list-style-type: none}
#links li            {display: block; float: left; text-align: center; width: 19%}
#links li a          {display: block; width: 100%; text-decoration: none; color: black;
                      background-color: white}
#links li a:hover    {color: white; background-color: rgb(0,153,102)}

#leftCol             {clear: left; float: left}
h1                   {font-size: 24px; letter-spacing: 5px; color: rgb(0, 153,102)}

#main                {float: left; width: 450px; margin-left: 10px; 
                      padding-left: 10px; border-left: 1px solid rgb(0,153,102);
                      padding-bottom: 15px}
#main img            {float: right; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px}

#main p              {margin-bottom: 10px}

address              {width: 100%; clear: left; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px;
                      border-top: 1px solid black; text-align: center;
                      padding-bottom: 15px}

.marquee             {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
                      width: 280px; height: 300px;
                      background-color: rgb(0, 153, 102); color:white; 
                      border: 5px inset white; 
                      padding:0px; overflow:hidden; position:relative}

#marqueeTxt1         {font-size: 1.4em; letter-spacing: 0.15em; border-bottom: 1px solid white}
input                {width: 120px; margin: 5px; font-size: 0.9em}
#marqueeButtons      {width: 280px; text-align: center}

#marqueeTxt1         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt2         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt3         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt4         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt5         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt6         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt7         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt8         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
#marqueeTxt9         {position: relative; padding: 4px 0 4px 0;}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 4
   Case Problem 3

   BYSO Web Page
   Author: Gavin Macken
   Date: 28 Feb `15  

   Filename:         byso.htm
   Supporting files: bstyles.css, byso.jpg, bysologo.jpg, marquee.js
-->
   <title>Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra</title>
   <link href="bstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "marquee.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="marqueeForm" action="">
   <div id="pageContent">

      <div id="head"><img src="bysologo.jpg" alt="Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra" /></div>

      <ul id="links">
         <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About BYSO</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Our Director</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Join BYSO</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="leftCol">
      <div class="marquee">
         <div id="marqueeTxt1" class="marqueeTxt">
            Schedule of Events
         </div>
         <div id="marqueeTxt2" class="marqueeTxt">
            Holiday Concert<br />
            December 14, 7:30 PM<br /> 
            Boise Civic Center
         </div>
         <div id="marqueeTxt3" class="marqueeTxt">
            Christmas Concert<br /> 
            Dec. 16, 7 PM<br /> 
            Our Savior Episcopal Church
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt4" class="marqueeTxt">
            Spring Concert<br />
            Feb. 27, 7 PM<br /> 
            Boise Civic Center
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt5" class="marqueeTxt">
            Easter Fanfare<br />
            March 14, 9 PM<br />
            Our Savior Episcopal Church
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt6" class="marqueeTxt">
            High School MusicFest<br />
            May 2, 3 PM<br />
            Boise Central High School
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt7" class="marqueeTxt">
            Summer Concert<br />
            June 15, 7:30 PM<br />
            Frontier Concert Hall
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt8" class="marqueeTxt">
            Fourth Fest<br />
            July 4, 4 PM<br />
            Canyon View Park
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt9" class="marqueeTxt">
            Frontier Days<br />
            August 9, 1 PM<br />
            Boise Concert Hall
         </div>     
      </div>

      <div id="marqueeButtons">
         <input type="button" id="startMarquee" value="Start Marquee" />
         <input type="button" id="stopMarquee" value="Pause Marquee" />
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="main">
         <h1>Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra</h1>
         <img src="byso.jpg" alt="" />
         <p>The Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra has delighted audiences worldwide with 
            beautiful music while offering the highest quality musical training to over 
            1,000 teens throughout Idaho for the past 30 years. BYSO 
            has established an outstanding reputation for its high quality sound, its 
            series of commissioned works, and collaborations with prominent musical groups 
            such as the Idaho and Boise Symphony Orchestras, the Montana Chamber 
            Orchestra, the Boise Adult Choir and the Western Symphony Orchestra. 
            Last year the group was invited to serve as the U.S. representative to 
            the 7th Annual World Festival of youth orchestras in Poznan, Poland.</p>
         <p>Leading this success for the past decade has been Boise Symphony artistic 
            director Denise Young. In a concert review by John Aehl, music critic for 
            the <i>Boise Times</i>, Roger Adler writes, "It is a pleasure to report that 
            the orchestra is playing better than ever."</p>
      </div>

    <address>
    BYSO &#183; 300 Mountain Lane &#183; Boise, Idaho  83702 &#183; (208) 555 - 9114
    </address>


   </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip...but if possible I'd like to fix this problem without changing any off the properties in the css file..

Comment: The main issue is a direct result of the `CSS`, so unless you make some changes there you'll have to add `CSS` into your html, which essentially overrides the `.css` file. Why would not want to change any of the properties in the `CSS`? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Cool...Well what you did works well, Thank you !!! Im going to keep playing with it as I know that I will be able to change the top position, by setting the initial style in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this problem.
Thanks to the .getComputedStyle method.
Thanks for the help everyone

```js
window.onload = defineMarquee;

var timeID;
var marqueeTxt = new Array();
var marqueeOff = true;



/* defineMarquee()
      Initializes the contents of the marquee, determines the
      top style positions of each marquee item, and sets the
      onclick event handlers for the document
*/
   function defineMarquee() {

   var topValue = 0;

   var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

   for(var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++){
      if (allElems[i].className == "marqueeTxt") marqueeTxt.push(allElems[i]);
   }

//Extract the "top" CSS class from marqueeTxt

   for(var i = 0; i < marqueeTxt.length; i++){
      if (window.getComputedStyle) {
       topValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(marqueeTxt[i]).getPropertyValue("top");}
       else if (marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle) {
         topValue = document.defaultView.marqueeTxt[i].currentStyle["top"];
       }
         marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topValue;
   }

 


   document.getElementById("startMarquee").onclick = startMarquee;
   document.getElementById("stopMarquee").onclick = stopMarquee;


}

/* startMarquee()
      Starts the marquee in motion
*/

   function startMarquee() {
      if(marqueeOff ==  true) {
         timeID = setInterval("moveText()", 50);
         marqueeOff = false;
      }
   }

/* stopMarquee()
   Stops the Marquee
*/

   function stopMarquee() {
      clearInterval(timeID);
      marqueeOff = true;
   }  

/* moveText ()
   move the text within the marquee in a vertical direction
*/

function moveText (){


for(var i = 0; i < marqueeTxt.length; i++) {
      
   topPos = parseInt(marqueeTxt[i].style.top);  
  
   if(topPos < -110) {
      topPos = 700;
   } else { topPos -= 1;
   }

   marqueeTxt[i].style.top = topPos + "px";

}

}
```

```css
*                    {margin: 0px; padding: 0px}
body                 {font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}

#pageContent         {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 30px; width: 800px}

#links               {display: block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;
                      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,153, 102); float: left}
#links               {list-style-type: none}
#links li            {display: block; float: left; text-align: center; width: 19%}
#links li a          {display: block; width: 100%; text-decoration: none; color: black;
                      background-color: white}
#links li a:hover    {color: white; background-color: rgb(0,153,102)}

#leftCol             {clear: left; float: left}
h1                   {font-size: 24px; letter-spacing: 5px; color: rgb(0, 153,102)}

#main                {float: left; width: 450px; margin-left: 10px; 
                      padding-left: 10px; border-left: 1px solid rgb(0,153,102);
                      padding-bottom: 15px}
#main img            {float: right; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px}

#main p              {margin-bottom: 10px}

address              {width: 100%; clear: left; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px;
                      border-top: 1px solid black; text-align: center;
                      padding-bottom: 15px}

.marquee             {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
                      width: 280px; height: 300px;
                      background-color: rgb(0, 153, 102); color:white; 
                      border: 5px inset white; 
                      padding:0px; overflow:hidden; position:relative}

#marqueeTxt1         {font-size: 1.4em; letter-spacing: 0.15em; border-bottom: 1px solid white}
input                {width: 120px; margin: 5px; font-size: 0.9em}
#marqueeButtons      {width: 280px; text-align: center}

#marqueeTxt1         {position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt2         {position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt3         {position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt4         {position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt5         {position: absolute; top: 330px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt6         {position: absolute; top: 410px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt7         {position: absolute; top: 490px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt8         {position: absolute; top: 570px; left: 20px}
#marqueeTxt9         {position: absolute; top: 640px; left: 20px}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 4
   Case Problem 3

   BYSO Web Page
   Author: Gavin Macken
   Date: 28 Feb `15  

   Filename:         byso.htm
   Supporting files: bstyles.css, byso.jpg, bysologo.jpg, marquee.js
-->
   <title>Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra</title>
   <link href="bstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "marquee.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="marqueeForm" action="">
   <div id="pageContent">

      <div id="head"><img src="bysologo.jpg" alt="Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra" /></div>

      <ul id="links">
         <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About BYSO</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Our Director</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Join BYSO</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="leftCol">
      <div class="marquee">
         <div id="marqueeTxt1" class="marqueeTxt">
            Schedule of Events
         </div>
         <div id="marqueeTxt2" class="marqueeTxt">
            Holiday Concert<br />
            December 14, 7:30 PM<br /> 
            Boise Civic Center
         </div>
         <div id="marqueeTxt3" class="marqueeTxt">
            Christmas Concert<br /> 
            Dec. 16, 7 PM<br /> 
            Our Savior Episcopal Church
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt4" class="marqueeTxt">
            Spring Concert<br />
            Feb. 27, 7 PM<br /> 
            Boise Civic Center
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt5" class="marqueeTxt">
            Easter Fanfare<br />
            March 14, 9 PM<br />
            Our Savior Episcopal Church
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt6" class="marqueeTxt">
            High School MusicFest<br />
            May 2, 3 PM<br />
            Boise Central High School
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt7" class="marqueeTxt">
            Summer Concert<br />
            June 15, 7:30 PM<br />
            Frontier Concert Hall
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt8" class="marqueeTxt">
            Fourth Fest<br />
            July 4, 4 PM<br />
            Canyon View Park
         </div>

         <div id="marqueeTxt9" class="marqueeTxt">
            Frontier Days<br />
            August 9, 1 PM<br />
            Boise Concert Hall
         </div>     
      </div>

      <div id="marqueeButtons">
         <input type="button" id="startMarquee" value="Start Marquee" />
         <input type="button" id="stopMarquee" value="Pause Marquee" />
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="main">
         <h1>Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra</h1>
         <img src="byso.jpg" alt="" />
         <p>The Boise Youth Symphony Orchestra has delighted audiences worldwide with 
            beautiful music while offering the highest quality musical training to over 
            1,000 teens throughout Idaho for the past 30 years. BYSO 
            has established an outstanding reputation for its high quality sound, its 
            series of commissioned works, and collaborations with prominent musical groups 
            such as the Idaho and Boise Symphony Orchestras, the Montana Chamber 
            Orchestra, the Boise Adult Choir and the Western Symphony Orchestra. 
            Last year the group was invited to serve as the U.S. representative to 
            the 7th Annual World Festival of youth orchestras in Poznan, Poland.</p>
         <p>Leading this success for the past decade has been Boise Symphony artistic 
            director Denise Young. In a concert review by John Aehl, music critic for 
            the <i>Boise Times</i>, Roger Adler writes, "It is a pleasure to report that 
            the orchestra is playing better than ever."</p>
      </div>

    <address>
    BYSO &#183; 300 Mountain Lane &#183; Boise, Idaho  83702 &#183; (208) 555 - 9114
    </address>


   </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```